# Espresso2.0 typeText(string) bug?

Tags: android-espresso

I am use the Espresso2.0.

```
String str = "Hello_world";
onView( withId(R.id.et_jumpfrom) )
        .perform(  typeText(str) ,  closeSoftKeyboard()  );
onView( withId(R.id.btn_jumpform_reshow))
        .perform( click() );

// check the result
onView( withId(R.id.tv_jumpfrom_display))
        .check( matches( withText(str) ));
```

when I use

```
typeText("hello")
```

the check() result is OK.

But, when I use

```
typeText("Hello_world");
```

the check is failed.

I checked the error message and found out the EditText actually was typed

```
H'e'l'l'o_'w'o'r'l'd
```

This is really weird. How can i resolve this problem?

---

The below is my whole code :

1. build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies {
       // Testing-only dependencies
       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
       androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1')
   }
   ```
2. Test

   ```
   import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
   import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
   @LargeTest
   public class JumpActivityTest {
       public String str = "Espresso_Test";

       @Rule
       public ActivityTestRule<JumpFromActivity> actvRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(JumpFromActivity.class);

       @Test
       public void changeText_sameActv() {
           onView(withId(R.id.et_jumpfrom))
                   .perform(typeText(str), closeSoftKeyboard());
           onView(withId(R.id.btn_jumpform_reshow))
                   .perform(click());

           // check the result
           onView(withId(R.id.tv_jumpfrom_display))
                   .check(matches(withText(str)));
       }     

   }
   ```
3. expect

   the EditText was typed "Espress_Test"
4. actual output

   ```
   android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "Espresso_Test"' doesn't match the selected view.
   Expected: with text: is "Espresso_Test"
   Got: "TextView{id=2131165188, res-name=tv_jumpfrom_display, visibility=VISIBLE, width=353, height=59, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=183.0, y=96.0, text=E's'p're's'so'_T'e'st, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

   at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:579)
   at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:82)
   ...
   ```

Then I saw the text in EditText is actually

```
text=E's'p're's'so'_T'e'st
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: why would you edit the guy's title and confuse everyone else? 
it doesn't make any difference for now but he is clearly stating using 2.0 in the very first line @JohnSaunders

Comment: @snwr, I cannot reproduce your issue. Please post both tests and expected outcomes and make sure you are using the right identifiers. It seems like you are using the wrong one, either in the test class or in the tested class

Comment: @appoll: I did not edit this title.

Comment: sorry, It's me who changed the title. Because i actually use Espresso 2.1, so I edit to make the title more accurate. If it confused other people, i will change it back

Comment: Does the EventIjector logcat output show apostrophes as well? (it looks something like this: `V/ESP_TRACE(29423): EventInjector:Injecting event for character (E) with key code (47) downtime: (11928619)`) If yes, what's your IME? What language is it in?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the IME.

baidu IME has this problem.

And it will be fine with the google IME.